# mod_rewrite rule looses one variable (regex issue)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I got the following mod_rewrite rule

`Rewriterule ^products/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /products/$2-$3-C$1 [R=301,L]`

So when there is a link like:

`http://www.domain.com/products/2930/Monet, Claude`

it should translate as

`http://www.domain.com/products/Monet-Claude-C2930`

However it somehow gets rids of `Claude` and translate it as:

`http://www.domain.com/products/Monet-C2930`

Isn't that weird? What's wrong with it?

**update**

I just noticed the problem is being caused by a rule above it: 
`Rewriterule ^products/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /products/$2-C$1 [R=301,L]` and i forgot to end it with the $ sign

Comment: It works perfectly for me at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: Your code looks ok, though it might be related to how the URL is encoded, say %20 instead of white space.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski of course, i forgot to end it with the $ sign :S

Comment: @FabrícioMatté of course, i forgot to end it with the $ sign :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it Is Must Be Work Test It

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$  /products/$2-$3-C$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks, yeah i know, check the updated question. I fixed it already haha

Comment: I Solve It By Put "**" instead Of "+" on "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" and A little change

Comment: No the issue was caused by the line before because i forgot to end it with `$` so it took the rest of the url without doing anything with it :s